# SUM of two timestampdiff in minutes

Tags: mysql, timestamp, sum

I've searched through many sites but was unable to find a solution to this.
I'm trying to sum two timestampdiffs when they are in minutes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from `table` 
WHERE
TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,first_date,second_date),
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,fourth_date,third_date)
) > 15 AND status='Pending'
```

This is where I am currently at but it returns an empty result.

Can anyone enlighten me with an answer to this? Thank you.

I've tried this as well but to no avail

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from `table` 
WHERE 
AddTime(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,first_date,second_date),
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,fourth_date,third_date)
    ) > 15 AND status='Pending'
```

and also this one

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from `table` 
    WHERE 
    (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,first_date,second_date)+TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,fourth_date,third_date))
        ) > 15 AND status='Pending'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, you are adding minute to minute, you can add minute to a date if you want to use `TIMESTAMPADD` function

Try this one

```
SELECT *
from table
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,first_date,second_date) + TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,fourth_date,third_date) > 120
```

Comment: my bad hahaha i had the correct sql statement all along and i didnt even realised. Thanks! :D